# AWS CloudSearch Error Unmartialing Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I seem to be bumping up against some limitation to CloudSearch that I can't figure out. I am working in .NET and I have a situation where there are a large number of 'playlists' that I would like to allow in the search, which makes a long query, but it seems to work for the most part.  However in some cases I am getting an error that I don't totally understand.  Here is the stack trace:

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonUnmarshallingException: Error unmarshalling response back from AWS.  ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.JsonErrorResponseUnmarshaller.Unmarshall(JsonUnmarshallerContext context) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Transform\JsonErrorResponseUnmarshaller.cs:line 103
   at Amazon.CloudSearchDomain.Model.Internal.MarshallTransformations.SearchResponseUnmarshaller.UnmarshallException(JsonUnmarshallerContext context, Exception innerException, HttpStatusCode statusCode) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\CloudSearchDomain\Generated\Model\Internal\MarshallTransformations\SearchResponseUnmarshaller.cs:line 92
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.JsonResponseUnmarshaller.UnmarshallException(UnmarshallerContext input, Exception innerException, HttpStatusCode statusCode) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Transform\ResponseUnmarshallers.cs:line 198
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.cs:line 78
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.cs:line 111
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.Handle(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ExceptionHandler.cs:line 38
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 204
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 78
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 45
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Signer.cs:line 38
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:line 72
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:line 84
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 45
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointResolver.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\EndpointResolver.cs:line 34
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Marshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Marshaller.cs:line 37
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.CloudSearchDomain.Internal.ProcessRequestHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\CloudSearchDomain\Custom\Internal\ProcessRequestHandler.cs:line 26
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 45
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\ErrorCallbackHandler.cs:line 44
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\MetricsHandler.cs:line 40
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RuntimePipeline.cs:line 135
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, IMarshaller`2 marshaller, ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AmazonServiceClient.cs:line 192
   at Amazon.CloudSearchDomain.AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient.Search(SearchRequest request) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\CloudSearchDomain\Generated\_bcl35\AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient.cs:line 132
   at SPTR.Gamut.Data.AWS.AwsCore.GetSearchResult(String searchString, Int32& totalFound, List`1& facets, Nullable`1 searchType, Boolean paginateAsList) in C:\RD\Commercial Software\SPECtrum\Gamut\Code\GamutBase\Data\AWS\AwsCore.cs:line 1427
   at SPTR.Gamut.SearchVM.DoSearch() in C:\RD\Commercial Software\SPECtrum\Gamut\Code\GamutBase\SearchVM.cs:line 224
```

The thing is, if I have no faceting in this it works fine, as soon as I turn on any facet it gets the error.  Also if I reduce to 100 playlists instead of 150 and turn on faceting in also works fine.  This all leads me to believe that there is some type of limit that it's hitting that is throwing the error.

Here is the data for the one that got the error:

Query (structure parser): (or (term 'door') (prefix boost=0.25 'door') (and (or (term 'door') (prefix boost=0.25 'door')) (term field=favoritedusers boost=1.5 '9219cfe5-9756-45e7-ae15-b5ca73748404')))

FilterQuery: (and (or keynote:'08710') objecttype:'10' (or playlists:'9i2frcy8' playlists:'uwpvqyxh' playlists:'0qtvwena' playlists:'2gqii0go' playlists:'8qj8cgvw' playlists:'l8a56uvd' playlists:'8lf98mhe' playlists:'0f7giujd' playlists:'ut1qckaj' playlists:'h4dbj7s9' playlists:'c9mm1dm6' playlists:'mjp0frtb' playlists:'j2ndnbri' playlists:'f854hpfj' playlists:'tb6li0qt' playlists:'8ox2i76j' playlists:'9cwmleut' playlists:'ny6cev1u' playlists:'1m4x5i1x' playlists:'ge251k0f' playlists:'ylne2cy8' playlists:'nvwwpybx' playlists:'xy3vlw6k' playlists:'4je6ema4' playlists:'rxb4jvuf' playlists:'be0cqgih' playlists:'h448us7o' playlists:'fq6ruon1' playlists:'101svsr1' playlists:'ti3nqavr' playlists:'u0h2bspq' playlists:'usoj1juy' playlists:'8hrw4h8o' playlists:'gr4n8x6a' playlists:'k8qy3c5r' playlists:'3wcgj6qp' playlists:'slqorl5t' playlists:'y5tyrdgy' playlists:'681wh04e' playlists:'dvp6mqor' playlists:'r5fe7di4' playlists:'fmtm0hn2' playlists:'q96rvp4q' playlists:'5p8c1v8o' playlists:'vivmluko' playlists:'wtneponn' playlists:'qeok75fn' playlists:'jni0x45c' playlists:'y9oh506q' playlists:'sgu0t3ta' playlists:'llk4ic2w' playlists:'2o0rh2yn' playlists:'6nfvkcx2' playlists:'jyg2cymq' playlists:'olqvouu4' playlists:'8q2t2eoo' playlists:'jxu400y7' playlists:'uy7vi8f0' playlists:'p1deaf2h' playlists:'70t9gpra' playlists:'4x8xwypa' playlists:'xrwwdfo4' playlists:'xjwwydlm' playlists:'nmgdgjxp' playlists:'5n0galk7' playlists:'avg3g9w7' playlists:'4hi5qxbf' playlists:'82v4tmgr' playlists:'8kl1sguf' playlists:'2vm68mfv' playlists:'i2c5bt61' playlists:'ibdrl9w8' playlists:'dxnn2y0y' playlists:'faqqq80p' playlists:'tlsad9cx' playlists:'6xuqmi30' playlists:'qtkibnnv' playlists:'jgbp6ux7' playlists:'hmekjdg6' playlists:'scgkd7i7' playlists:'quup0wig' playlists:'ux42kss3' playlists:'828u9ir1' playlists:'bx8eevau' playlists:'mhe0g4a4' playlists:'mp15xd5c' playlists:'qedatlm7' playlists:'dxtbs3wy' playlists:'g5n8jtai' playlists:'dmbexfiq' playlists:'suvegdq7' playlists:'imx2ahs6' playlists:'3ijkufbe' playlists:'4keg8svd' playlists:'w24ddnig' playlists:'ytvlqovy' playlists:'xpwypcof' playlists:'wa8nnfck' playlists:'p7vv2osu' playlists:'s0tamtvw' playlists:'5322h108' playlists:'fcq853br' playlists:'ev4etn0y' playlists:'s71e1rq9' playlists:'t1bmhv5v' playlists:'wd54ybpa' playlists:'ta76327c' playlists:'6ca3h73p' playlists:'cv0dn0i0' playlists:'smil74bn' playlists:'1o1y133q' playlists:'4fr5cj6h' playlists:'49h3ybcc' playlists:'9g891fdi' playlists:'i01h0dit' playlists:'1n0mx1gs' playlists:'q2oea37k' playlists:'f0v6r6yn' playlists:'d1lao5gp' playlists:'bgaa5ix3' playlists:'lg4tttop' playlists:'2b8sl742' playlists:'6uqj5dl7' playlists:'3t9cb7wj' playlists:'gylul16i' playlists:'3xgjgmw7' playlists:'epk4pc39' playlists:'wmcmovnk' playlists:'ko2jphlb' playlists:'u87cgxct' playlists:'cs1lsia4' playlists:'i2jjsa7r' playlists:'rr3161xq' playlists:'d6oemfis' playlists:'4o8gd9he' playlists:'wrrl3e2s' playlists:'5bt9n80s' playlists:'2mwvrovm' playlists:'rc17tj4d' playlists:'y4sprfou' playlists:'06hluw5h' playlists:'d22u2nfn' playlists:'tx97dgvo' playlists:'2kb85l0g' playlists:'30amwf4j' playlists:'u3yu0euy' playlists:'sh9sf9yj' playlists:'cbah1wub' playlists:'kbbwdo2p' playlists:'xio2uj1m' playlists:'eshkknye'))

Facet: {"category":{}, "assemblycode":{}, "keynote":{buckets:["08710"]}, "omniclass":{}, "playlists":{}, "status":{}, "workplanebased":{}, "host":{}, "sourcefile":{}}

Query Options: {"fields":["assemblycode^1","assemblydescription^1","category^1","filename^1.5","keynote^1","keywords^1.5","name^1.5","omniclass^1","omniclasstitle^1","parametersearchvalues^0.5"]}

I have found the page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/limits.html and looked over it.  However I don't see a limit I would be hitting. I don't have 1024 clauses, I have about 150.  Get max is 8190 bytes; I have added up my strings and it comes to about 3500 characters.  I don't know exactly how CloudSearch API formats the get but I doubt it would more than double the length.

Can anyone tell me what the issue is that I'm hitting?  Also is there a good way in the .NET SDK to count the bytes for a get to be sure I'm not hitting that?

Comment: You seem to be assuming UTF-8 chars are one byte, but they can be multi-byte especially for non-English characters. May be a red herring but I wanted to point that out

Comment: Good point.  However in this case all the values are id's that are generated from only numbers or alpha English characters...  I'm not by any means an expert on character encoding but I don't think that's an issue here.  The strings are above so let me know if there are many multi-byte characters there.  There may be a few but I think the vast majority are single...

Answer (score 0):

ok well I still don't know what the limitation is but I found a way to work around it.  I'm posting it here as an answer to help anyone else dealing with this situation or something similar, but if someone knows what limitation I'm hitting or how to deal with this better I'll accept that answer...

So I ended up breaking my search up into multiple requests.  Basically if the list of playlists is over 100 I broke it up into chunks of 100 playlists and submitted a request for each chunk.  Then I took the result sets from each and put them back together into a final result set.  This works with a few items I would be aware of if you are going to use this method:

- Of course it's a little slower as you are searching multiple times instead of just once.
- If you are paginating you would need to store EACH search request/response object to get the next set instead of just one and do the same thing when getting the next page.
- Search quality may be reduced.  If you pull the top 5 from 2 different groups there is no guarantee that it will be the top 10 from the whole.  The top 5 from group 2 may be ranked as 30-35 in the overall but would show up as 6-10 in the split result set.

In my case while these aren't ideal they are acceptable limitations...